# Authenticate to Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

All,
I'm hitting a rate limit all the time. I'm just trying to pull the latest status from my own timeline. I'm using the following code to make that happen:

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={$username}&count={$how_many}";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$contents = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
if ( ! empty( $contents ) ) {
    // Decode it.
    $tweet = json_decode( $contents );
    // Cache it for next time.
    set_transient( $id.'-'.$username, $tweet, 60*60*12 ); // 3 hour cache
}
```

This works fine but I hit my rate limit of 150 requests per hour all the time. I've read that if I authenticate to the API the rate limit is lifted. Can anyone explain how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to be refreshing your status more than every 4 minutes? I would be guessing not, you're actually setting a 3 hour cache in your code so why not use it?

```
if(get_transient($id.'-'.$username) === false) {
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={$username}&
    count={$how_many}";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    $contents = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
    if ( ! empty( $contents ) ) {
        // Decode it.
        $tweet = json_decode( $contents );
        // Cache it for next time.
        set_transient( $id.'-'.$username, $tweet, 60*60*12 ); // 3 hour cache
    }
}
```

Obviously you can reduce how long the cache lasts if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The rate for the Twitter REST API is exactly as you state - 150 for unauthenticated requests (by ip address), and 350 for Oauth authenticated requests. What I've done in the past is to look at your queries, and using the Search API - make a more efficient call. Or, to perform more calls from different virtual IP addresses.

From https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting#rest
  Unauthenticated calls are permitted 150 requests per hour. Unauthenticated calls are measured against the public facing IP of the server or device making the request.
  OAuth calls are permitted 350 requests per hour and are measured against the oauth_token used in the request.

You can't get whitelisted for more than that. Here's a [link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting#rest) to back that up.

For an example with PHP directly from twitter, try [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples) and see the PHP twitter library. Essentially you have to make an Oauth connection by setting up a Twitter App, and receiving the Oauth Key & Secret.